# Why the pipe 'translate' could not be found?

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, ngx-translate

I created a component `cookie.component` in `modal/` folder with the `component.module`which contains the necessairy to make the module translate work

`cookie.component.module`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        FontAwesomeModule,
    ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: []
})
export class CookieModule {
    constructor(
        private library: FaIconLibrary
        ) {
      }
 }
```

I import this component in a `guard/cookie.guard`  which i called in `app-routing.module`

`guard/cookie.guard`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ModalController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CookieComponent } from '../modal/cookie/cookie.component';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CookiesGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private modalController: ModalController,
        private platform: Platform
    ) {}

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            if (this.platform.url().includes("http") && localStorage.getItem("useAnalytics") == null) {
                this.modalController.create({
                    component: CookieComponent,
                    cssClass: "cookie-modal",
                    backdropDismiss: false
                }).then(m => {
                    m.present();
                }).catch(err => console.error(err));
            } else resolve(true);
        });
    }
}
```

and here is the `app-routing.module`

```
...
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { CookiesGuard } from './guard/cookie.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule),
    canActivate: [CookiesGuard, LaunchGuard, ProgramChoseGuard]
  },
...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am getting  `The pipe 'translation' could not be found` even though modal `cookie.component` has the necessary imported...

Any idea how to make the translation in this specific case ?

The goal for me is to have a modal has a guard with the translation, note that if I replace in `cookie.component.html` the {{ELEMENT.el | translate }} by normal non-translated text it works well. And translation works on all other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `imports: [TranslateModule]` into whatever module the `CookiesGuard` is declare in.

Comment: Thx, I had to set declarations, entryComponentsin my module file in addtion to import the module translate ;)